# Simplifying Square Roots Frustration

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

Okay, I'm really frustrated with this.

So, when you have $3 \sqrt 5 + 5 \sqrt 5$,
you get $8\sqrt5$, right?

Okay, so what do I do for here:
$\sqrt{11} - 3 \sqrt{11}$

Is it just $-3  \sqrt{11}$ ?
What about for $6 \sqrt 2 + 4  \sqrt{50}$ ?
Do I multiply the $6 \sqrt{2}$ so that I can make what's inside of the square root equal to $50$?

Answer (score 2):

- $\sqrt{11}-3\sqrt{11}=\color{red}{1}\cdot\sqrt{11}-3\sqrt{11}=-2\sqrt{11}.$
- $6\sqrt 2+4\sqrt{50}=6\sqrt 2+4\color{blue}{\sqrt{2\cdot 5^2}}=6\sqrt{2}+4\cdot \color{blue}{5\sqrt 2}=6\sqrt 2+20\sqrt 2=26\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Uh, can you explain what you did on the second bullet? I have no idea what you did.

Comment: @johny: Do you understand $\sqrt{2\cdot 5^2}=5\sqrt 2$?

Comment: @johny $$\sqrt{2*25}=5\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Yes, I do understand that.

Comment: @johny: OK. Please clarify what you don't understand in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Essam. mathlover, I didn't know why you squared 5 instead of just writing 25, then showing how that is broken down into 5.

Comment: @johny: $\sqrt{a^2}=a$ for $a\ge 0$. That's why I wrote $5^2$ instead of $25$.

Comment: Okay, I just wasn't used to seeing it like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it might help to take things a little more symbolically. Without worrying about what $x$ is for now, think about $3x + 5x$. Clearly that's $8x$, just as you thought.

For the next problem you have $x - 3x$. The answer is $-2x$. Let's say $x = 1$. Then this boils down to $1 - 3 = -2$. When we put $x = \sqrt{11}$ back into the picture, we get $\sqrt{11} - 3\sqrt{11} = -2\sqrt{11}$.

With the third problem, think about $x \neq y$. We have $6x + 4y$ and you're pretty much stuck unless you can figure out some way to restate $x$ in terms of $y$ or vice versa. It turns out that $\sqrt{50} = 5\sqrt{2}$ (so $y = 5x$). Therefore $$6\sqrt{2} + 4\sqrt{50} = 6\sqrt{2} + 4(5\sqrt{2}) = 6 + 20\sqrt{2} = 26\sqrt{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Compare:

\begin{align}
  x - 3 x
  &= 1x - 3 x \\
  &= (1 - 3)x \\
  &= -2 x
\end{align}

to

\begin{align}
  \sqrt{11} - 3 \sqrt{11}
  &= 1\sqrt{11} - 3 \sqrt{11} \\
  &= (1 - 3)\sqrt{11} \\
  &= -2 \sqrt{11}
\end{align}